# Multiple queries in phpmyadmin - Distance using coordinates, Slope, Intercept, Angle, and few more

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, excel

I having around 500 excel sheets in .csv format with data captured for my experiment having following columns in place.

[image]

Now I need to calculate the following parameters using this data. I have done these in excel, however doing this repeatedly for each excel so many times is difficult, so I want to write an SQL query in PhpmyAdmin will help some time.

1. **Last charecter typed** - need to capture last charecter from the column 'CharSq'
2. *Slope (in column J) =(B3-B2)/(A3-A2)
3. Intercept (in column K) =B2-(A2*(J3))
4. Angle (in degrees) =MOD(DEGREES(ATAN2((A3-A2),(B3-B2))), 360) -
5. Index of Difficulty =LOG(((E1/7.1)+1),2)
6. Speed Value length (if speed value length >3, then mark as 1 or else 0) = =IF(LEN(D3) >= 3, "1","0")
7. Wrong Sequence (if I3=I2,then mark search time, else actual time) =IF(I3=I2,"Search Time","Actual Time")
8. Mark charecter into (1,2,3) = =IF(I2="A",1, IF(I2="B",2, IF(I2="C",3, 0)))
   [image]

I have started with this SQL query SELECT id, type, charSq, substr(charSq,-1,1) AS TypedChar, xCoordinate, yCoordinate, angle, distance, timestamp, speed FROM table 1 WHERE 1

Need help for the rest of the parameters. Thanks.

Note - I am going to run this in phpMyAdmin SQL

Orginal Data captured (Indian language - so while uploading in excel / db make sure you have UTF8 format - [Original data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10WH7aEx0z_1kdh6dJZGypySlvrj6qfpreLmGitjzhzw/edit?usp=sharing)

Analysed data (desired SQL query) - [All blue header columns and respective cell have formulaas in Sheet2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G2UVOoEnNVyKgP3o51P__XpoU1U2c9tr4SamaM5teNM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Y'day I have updated it to MySQL- 8.0.18 version.  Each excel will have around 500-600 such records.

Comment: Hi @Akina as per your suggestion, I have added the orginal data and analysed data as links.  Let me know if you need more information.  This is Indian Language so it should be set in UTF8.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table test.Table10 select mm.myid,mm.id,mm.type1 as GESTURE,MM.CHARSQ,MM.TYPE2 as TYPEDCHAR,MM.MYCHAR,MM.XCOR,MM.YCOR,MM.SLOPE,l4-(l2*(SLOPE)) as Intercept,
if (ANGLE1<0, (ANGLE1+360) , ANGLE1 ) as ANGLE0,MM.DISTANCE,MM.DW,MM.INDDIFF,MM.TIME1,MM.SPEED,MM.SPDFILT,MM.TIMETYPE from (select c11.*,((YCOR-l4)/(XCOR-l2)) as SLOPE,MOD(DEGREES (ATAN2((YCOR-l4),(XCOR-l2))), 360) as ANGLE1,(YCOR-l4)/(XCOR-l2) ATT,LOG2(((DW)+1)) as INDDIFF,
if(TYPE2=(LAG(TYPE2) OVER (
PARTITION BY MYID
ORDER BY ID)),"Search Time","Actual Time") as TIMETYPE,case when type2="A" then "1"
when type2="B" then 2
when type2="C" then 3
else 0
end as MYCHAR from (SELECT b.*,LEAD(XCOR) OVER (
PARTITION BY charsq) l1,LAG(XCOR) OVER (
PARTITION BY MYID
ORDER BY ID) l2,LEAD(YCOR) OVER (
PARTITION BY MYID) l3,LAG(YCOR) OVER (
PARTITION BY MYID
ORDER BY ID) l4,distance/7.1 as DW,IF(length(speed) >= 3, "1","0") as SPDFILT,RIGHT(charSq,1) as TYPE2 FROM test.table2 b) c11) mm
```